# Do Python Virtual Enviroments Support Enviroment Variables Scoped To Only The Virtual Enviroment?

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtual-machine

I am having a difficult time finding this online, but maybe that's because I don't fully understand what I'm talking about.

I'm wondering if VMs in Python have support for "virtual environment variables" so that I can just enter a VM and rely on environment variables set within the VM. This way I wouldn't have to store API keys in my machine's native environment variables.

Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: You can modify your virtual env activation script to set local environment variables, e.g. on Windows `set SECRET_API_KEY=aabbccdd` and then in your python `api_key = os.environ.get("SECRET_API_KEY")`.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables come from the OS, and loaded into the Python interpreter; they aren't "virtual".

If you want project-specific variables, you can try using [`python-dotenv`](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/), or other config libraries rather than needing to "populate" your OS-dependent settings for defining variables. Then make sure you ignore `.env` files from source-control...

Otherwise, sure, edit `~/.bashrc`, for example in a Linux VM, and those are inherited by any process ran by that user, and are not stored on your host anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually a windows user and am very novice with Linux, but that is beside the point. I just wouldn't be able to do the suggestion concerning `~/.bash`. 

Would it make more sense to just store my variables in a JSON file and import that file rather than messing around with all this environment stuff?

Perhaps it's worth mentioning, I don't really understand why so many platforms recommend putting API keys in the environment variables. I just know I am not the most familiar with security protocol, so I try to drink the kool-aid wherever possible and assume it keeps me protected.

Comment: If you were running your code in the cloud, you could use credentials store there (AWS Credentials Manager, for example). Hashicorp Vault is an open-source alternative... But JSON files will certainly work, however, so does a `.env` file, like I said. Env-Vars are local to your machine, and API keys should not be committed into source-control as plaintext

Comment: Thanks again, @OneCricketeer. I can confirm I'm running everything locally. What do you mean by "source-control?" Would that be, for example, GitHub (in the event that I was using GitHub as a code repository)? Also, is there some sort of 'best practice' for storing these things? Would `.env` be better than JSON, for example? Currently, I just keep my credentials locked up in a database generated by KeePass Password Manager, and I set up Jupyter Notebooks to collect the decryption password via user input with getpass() and use the PyKeePass library to extract the credentials from the database.

Comment: Git, SVN, etc. Yes. PyKeePaas sounds like it'll work for you, but obviously wont if you were to share your code with others... There's no reason to use a JSON file when you could just write a plain Python file with variables and `import` it rather than `json.load` anything else. Python also has `configparser` built-in for similar purposes